# First Tick of Quotation Mark Dark in Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm using GNOME Terminal heavily, and have a rendering issue: for lower zoom, gnome renders the first tick `'` of a quotation mark `"` darker than the other, as shown in this image:

[image]

This is difficult for me because I can't quickly distinguish `"` from `'`.

This aberrant rendering disappears for higher zoom. It does not happen in `xterm`. It persists for different choices of font, and some other colours, as the link shows. I'm using 
Ubuntu 16.04 and 
GNOME Term 3.18.3.

Does anyone know what's the source of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNOME Terminal just uses Pango for font rendering, as pretty much all GTK+ apps.

The fonts it uses are vector fonts, which look great at somewhat larger sizes, yet at tiny sizes issue like this can appear. The glyphs are imagined to be drawn on a surface of much higher resolution, then downscaled and antialiased to the requested size.

When downscaled, the difference between the horizontal offset of the two ticks probably becomes a non-integer, let's say 2.2 pixels (or any other value). Due to this non-integer offset, antialiasing produces different mapping into actual screen pixels.

Let's take a similar, but hypothetical example. Let character cells be 6 pixels wide, and the `"` symbol defined as two rectangles in the font. Imagine that `gnome-terminal` first draws the symbol on a canvas which is 6 * 1024 = 6144 pixels wide, each pixel becomes "on" (foreground color) of "off" (background color), no values in between. The first tick happens to fall from coordinates (0-based) 1024 to 2047, while the second ones happens to fall from 3300 to 4323.

Now let's scale down by a factor of 1024. The first tick exactly falls on pixel 1 (0-based, that is, "second" pixel), no antialiasing required. The given pixel will be exactly of the color of your foreground, and its adjacent pixels will be exactly of the color of your background.

The second tick falls partially (78%) on pixel 3, partially (22%) on pixel 4. So, how should these pixels be lit up? Read up on *antialiasing* as well as *subpixel rendering* to understand some of the tricks done here, but no matter what you do from software, it cannot be made look as sharp as the one that falls exactly on a pixel.

xterm supports (and defaults to) bitmap fonts, fonts that don't have antialiasing, each pixel is exactly either of the foreground or of the background color. Each of these fonts was designed for a particular size, and not meant to be scaled.

I don't think GNOME Terminal ever supported bitmap fonts. It used to have an option to disable antialiasing, but no longer has that either. (It *might* still be available using some Pango or Fontconfig magic, I don't know.)

A few ideas to mitigate the problem:

- Choose a terminal emulator that supports bitmap fonts. (As a GNOME Terminal developer I personally don't recommend this option :-D.)
- Try other fonts.
- Use color schemes of higher contrast (e.g. avoid dark blue on black).
- Increase the font size.
- If (or whenever) feasible, replace your monitor with a better resolution one. (For example, my 15" laptop with 1366x768 resolution died about a year ago, and bought a 15" 1920x1080 one. This made a true difference, I'd never go back to the lower resolution. And this is still nowhere near cutting edge available on the market.)

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll try some of these options and report post a comment if I find a good solution to this particular issue.